# Search and Replace a text string from text file using python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Badly need assistance on this:

```
f = open('/Volumes/Personal/example.text','r+')

for line in f:
    print(line, end='')
    if (line.startswith("path = ")) in f:
        line = CurrentFilePath + "\n" 
        f.write(line)
        print ("Success!!!!")
    else:
        print('Errorrrr!!!')
```

this line of code just reads the file, and as soon as the line which needs to be read and then replaced, it throws an error! Please help. Very very new to python.

Comment: why the `in f` in the if statement? is this the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I dont get error, it reads the that text file. But, when the line to be read is the one which I'm expecting to be replaced, it goes to else block!

Comment: @Francesco f just a variable for storing the file object

Comment: I'm not getting my program executed at if (line.startswith("path=") in f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your `if` statement:

```
if (line.startswith("path = ")) in f:
```

When you reach a line that start with "path = ", that line evaluates to:

```
if True in f:
```

...which doesn't really make sense. Files don't contain boolean values. Simply removing the `in f` will get you past that; it's not doing anything for you here.

Comment: OKay.. Great. That worked, can you do me a favour now? The string is not being replaced, can you help me with that?

Comment: @VighneshPai Sounds like that should be a new question.

Comment: @VighneshPai Why would you assume that it will be replaced, if you are never *replacing* it in the code?

Comment: @glibdud Please help dude, I'm really struck here.!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `True in f` always returns `False`. This is why only the else block is hit

Comment: @CPanda I'm replacing entire line!

Comment: @VighneshPai where exactly?

Comment: @VighneshPai You might want to search for "python replace text in file". There have been a number of questions on that subject.

Comment: @glibdud please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598728/replace-entire-line-in-a-text-file-based-on-search-using-python

Answer (score 0):

`f` is an iterator and `in` operator in `for` loop is made to call `next()` on it. What is `in` doing with `if`? Check the syntax for `if`. Delete `in f` from that line and hopefully it will work.